# Prevent Page Caching and Back Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to prevent the back button being used by expiring the pages.
I have been trying to find an article on here to help and nothing works.

I have the function below that I call as the first thing on all my pages.

I call it in the Page_Load handler, is that the right place ?

I see no errors which is good, but my application just reacts as if there is no change. The back/forward buttons work and the pages display as normal and don't expire.

**UPDATE:**

As an added layer of security, what I want is the page to time out so if they use the "back" button they won't get the previous page. I have F5 covered so that doesn't repeat posts, and login is covered, if as I abandon the Session when they log out. But I want to stop the back button showing the previous page and force them to use the app navigation to get around my application.

I've known this functionality to fail penetration testing so I want to cover that off before I get to that point.

J

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        MyWebApplication.SetPageStatus(Response);
        ....
    }

    internal static void SetPageStatus(System.Web.HttpResponse oResponse)
    {
        oResponse.ClearHeaders();
        oResponse.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
        oResponse.Expires = 0;
        oResponse.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        oResponse.Buffer = true;
        oResponse.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        oResponse.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow);
        oResponse.Cache.SetNoStore();
        oResponse.Cache.SetRevalidation(System.Web.HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    }
```

Comment: Aside from "prevent the back button being used" what are you trying to accomplish? Sometimes the approach we attempt isn't necessarily the correct one for our end goal.

Comment: try setting the ExpiresAbsolute property to DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d) and the Response.Expires to -1500;

Comment: please read this :[**post/redirect/get approach**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)